# Show parent page content on a child page - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have been trying for the past couple days to show the content from a parent page on a child page, but I wasn’t able to do so. Most of the codes I found were to show child page content on a parent page and had a loop.

What I’m looking to do is just grab the text from the parent page and display it on the child page, no loops needed.

Any help is appreciated. 
Thank you.

Comment: Is something like [get_ancestors()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_ancestors) what you are looking for? The first in the array returned should be the immediate parent and you can get the data from there.

Comment: How would i display the content of the parrent page using get_ancestors()? I tried the following but it just showed an Array. 
<?php $ancestors =  get_ancestors($post->ID, 'page' ); ?>

Comment: The immediate parent (I think) is the one at 0 (the first one), but see what it gives you. Then use `get_post()` (as `get_page()` is deprecated) and figure out what you need in that array. Kind of like what superUntitled did below which is probably a better way.

Comment: @craniumonempty this is what i've done so far. Now its displaying the image in the parent page on the child page but not the text. I'm not sure why.

 <?php $ancestors = get_ancestors($post->ID, 'page' );
$parent = get_post($post->post_parent);
echo $parent->post_content;
 ?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `post_parent`

```
 <?php 
     $parent_id = $post->post_parent;
     $parent_post = get_post($parent_id);
     $parent_content = $parent_post->post_content;
     echo $parent_content;
  ?>
```

Don't forget to use `wp_reset_query();` in order to get the current page content.

Comment: I've got those errors: 
-Warning: Missing argument 1 for get_page() and 
-Fatal error: Cannot use object of type WP_Post as array

Comment: @user2334436 are you using `get_page()` somewhere?

Comment: I just tested this again, it worked this time but its only showing the image from the parent page not the text.

Comment: Sorry it is not working for you, I have not tested this code, so am not 100% sure of the outcome. I would try to remove the apply filters and the str_replace? what happens when you `echo $content_post->post_content;`